# Is it a good practice to wrap Masstransit for CQRS implementation?

Tags: c#, message-queue, microservices, cqrs, masstransit

I would rather have a separate `CommandBus` and `EventBus` and also `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and `IEventHandler<TCommand>`  so that an `OrderEventHandler` class looks like:

```
public class OrderEventHandler :
    IEventHandler<OrderPlaced>,
    IEventHandler<OrderRegistrantAssigned>,
    IEventHandler<OrderTotalsCalculated>,
    IEventHandler<OrderConfirmed>,
    IEventHandler<OrderExpired>,
    IEventHandler<SeatAssignmentsCreated>,
    IEventHandler<SeatAssigned>,
    IEventHandler<SeatAssignmentUpdated>,
    IEventHandler<SeatUnassigned>
{ 
    public void Handle(OrderPlaced @event){...}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

A possible solution can be providing an adopter between `Masstransit` infrastructure and my `CQRS`(like `ConsumerToHandlerAdopter<T>`which only exposes the context details I generally need ).

But since I'm new to `Masstransit`, I can't get my head around the issues I might have to deal with later.

**So my question is:**
Does it generally worth to wrap Masstransit so that I deal with my own Infrastructure?

Comment: are you using a message queue/bus to synchronise the read model and write model? Could you have a look at my question here? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/378205/implementing-cqrs-inside-a-microservice +1.

Comment: Uncle Bob: Don’t marry the framework! Oh, you can use the framework - just don’t couple to it. Keep it at arm’s length. Treat the framework as a detail that belongs in one of the outer circles of the architecture. Don’t let it into the inner circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use MassTransit to implement CRQS extensively, but only for command handling.

The reason for not to use messaging infrastructure to synchronise write and read models are discussed many times. The main reason there is that you have a chance of persisting a change and not publishing an event, because these are two different pieces of infrastructure. Unless you use something like DTC, you will not be able to guarantee the consistency among models.

Also, at this point we also prefer to stay away from the "God handler" classes. MassTransit is particularly good at enforcing the SRP (single responsibility principle) by separating each consumer to a separate class.

For general domain event-based integration (reactive event processing), we also use MassTransit.

You can also have events that implement more than one message interface and by this you will have more comprehensive event processing:

```
public interface CustomerRegistered
{
    string FullName { get; }
}

public interface OrderPlaced
{
    string Reference { get; }
    List<OrderLine> Lines { get; }
}

public class NewCustomerOrderedStuff : CustomerRegistered, OrderPlaced
{
...
}

public class CustomerRegisteredConsumer : IConsumer<CustomerRegistered>

public class OrderPlacedConsumer : IConsumer<OrderPlaced>
```

And each of those consumers will have different concern and can live in a separate bounded context (service).

Comment: Thanks a million @Alexey Zimarev, I'm using rabbitmq as transport layer. I was aimed to represent my aggregates at the saga and whenever they  became consistent, then publish the events returned by calling an `aggregate.method()`. I don't need the aggregates after they get a certain state, so I can delete them.

Comment: I have a couple of projects where I use sagas as aggregates. This works quite well but it does not have separate read and write models. At the same time, I have made a saga persistence for EventStore https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/MassTransit.EventStoreIntegration  and by using it I can have event-sourced saga, building read models using projections, which are connected via the EventStore catch-up subscription.

Comment: I'm gad to see somebody have done it.But I guess the issue with not having an event store (or some kind of batch event publishing) there is that I might publish the facts that happened partially as you mentioned; which might be manageable using checking the state and changing it if all of the facts have been published successfully (If fits the domain).

Comment: Yeah, having a proper event store is important when doing event sourcing. Some people use Kafka with indefinitely retention for this purpose but there are mixed opinions about this. When you use event sourcing, the issue with events being published is getting worse since it will close the option to replay events, if projections and event consumers from other contexts are listening to the same bus.

Comment: I still wonder how to read the events from event store and publish them as commands through mass transit, and whether the conversion of events to commands should happen at source microservice or somewhere else!!? Thank you.

Comment: Events never get converted to commands. Persisted events describe something that happened. Commands indicate the intention for something to happen.

Comment: I mean some events from service 'A' may trigger some commands of service 'B'. Where should I read the event and call the command? Or I should not convert them to commands and react to events?

Comment: This is a reaction. This involves converting domain events to integration events and either writing them to an integration stream or publishing these events to some message bus. Reactors consume these events and produce necessary actions inside their own bounded contexts. You might also call it a "reactive ACL".

Comment: I guess I ask d my question uncertainly. Is it Ok for service 'B' to read the events from a kafka topic which is being consumed by service 'A' as it's event store and react to the event, or an ACL should read the kafka topic and send command to service 'A' in a big system with many services like an ERP?

Comment: And another question that's provoked my thoughts since the day you guided me about 2PC, is that how can rabbitmq help with events without CQRS? While storing data and firing integration events cannot be done at the same tranaction.

Comment: Yes, this is a potential issue and I have no real answer to that. My observation is that RMQ is _very_ reliable. If changes are persisted in a transactional manner and then we publish events to the bus, we can be quite certain (although not 100%) certain that it happened. We run RMQ for years, processing millions of messages per day and never got to a problem. It might be a network issue though but in this case persistence would not work either, unless they are in completely different networks.